# At what rates can creatures in a conservative cellular automata expand?

Tags: cellular-automata

Let $A$ be a finite set, and suppose $0\in A$.

For each $a\in A\setminus\{0\}$, let $w_{a}$ be a positive integer called the weight of $a$, and let $w_{0}=0$. Give $A$ the discrete topology and $A^{\mathbb{Z}}$ the product topology. We say that a mapping $\phi:A^{\mathbb{Z}}\rightarrow A^{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a one-dimensional cellular automaton if $\phi$ is continuous and if $\phi\tau=\tau\phi$ where $\tau(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}=(x_{n-1})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is the shift map. Let
$\Sigma(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}w_{x_{n}}$. We say that $\phi$ is conservative for the weights $(w_{a})_{a\in A}$ if $\Sigma(\mathbb{x})=\Sigma(\phi(\mathbb{x}))$ for all $\mathbb{x}\in\mathbb{A}^{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Suppose that $f,g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ are strictly increasing and nowhere zero. Then we say that
$f\simeq g$ if there are $r,s$ where $f(n)\leq r\cdot g(rn)$ and
$g(n)\leq s\cdot f(sn)$ for all $n$.

Suppose now that $\Sigma(\mathbb{x})<\infty$. Then define
the width $W(\mathbb{x})=\max(\{m-n|x_{m}\neq 0,y_{n}\neq 0\})$.

Let $G(\phi,\mathbb{x}):\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be defined by
$G(\phi,\mathbb{x})(n)=W(\phi^{n}(\mathbb{x}))$.

Easier question: Let $f_{r}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ be the function where
$f_{r}(n)=\lfloor 1+n^{r}\rfloor$. Are the real numbers $r\in[0,1]$ such that $f_{r}\simeq G(\phi,\mathbb{x})$ for some conservative $\phi$ and $\mathbb{x}$ with $\Sigma(\mathbb{x})<\infty$ precisely the rational numbers? What if we required each $\phi$ to also be reversible.

Harder question: Is there a characterization of the set of all functions $f$ where $f\simeq G(\phi,\mathbb{x})$ for some $\phi$ which is conservative with respect to some system of weights and $\mathbb{x}$? What if each $\phi$ were also required to be reversible?

Comment: Do you have a construction in mind that realizes all the rational numbers?

Comment: For square root expansion, simply take a moving blue particle trapped between two red particles. When the blue particle hits a red particle, the blue particle bounces in the other direction and the red particle is pushed one unit away. More complicated constructions can make $\sqrt[n]{x}$ growth and other fractional rational power growth rates.

Comment: Have you (or someone else) solved this? I think it's extremely interesting and I am considering a bounty.